# Zurb foundation: ads being cut off

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a fairly typical layout create in Zurb Foundation 3.  Here is a row, eight columns for the left (containing an Orbit slider) and then 4 columns for the ad on the right ("fluke" ad) and the box below the ad, which works fine on Desktop:

[image: desktop]

The issue is when I go to iPad width and the grid re-sizes.  The right edge of the ad is cut off, as in the next image (appliances ad). This is due to the ads being served in iframes. How can I prevent this?

[image: ipad]

I have tried setting a wrapping div on the ad to min-width 300px (ad is 300px). I had tried just setting width to 300px, which holds the ad size but then the 8-column block on the right does not reduce to allow the ad to fit.

Comment: Can you show your markup so we can take a look at it and see what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have the width="" property set on your iframed advertisements. You can trick foundation into keeping your ad content fluid by telling the framework that it is an iframed video using flexvideo.

```
<div class="flex-video">
    <iframe width="420" height="315"
            src="../ads/yourfilenamehere.swf"
            frameborder="0"
            allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div><!--/flex-video-->
```

adding this class to the div around your iframe will keep them responsive.

Comment: I will try this, thanks.  In the meantime, I had set my viewport initial scale to be 0.8 and that has worked as well.

Comment: setting the viewport to 0.8 will work great for ipads, but other tablets might run into issues with this. Ipads show a slightly higher resolution than they are supposed to. Just as a heads up it might cause issues in the future